# How to add a native extension to Adobe Flash CS5.5

Tags: ios, flash, air, adobe

Hey guys I am working on an IPhone app and I don't quite understand on how to add an native extension to it.  I need to access the address book so I am using Contact Editor - http://extensionsforair.com/extensions/contact-editor/#comment-7488 which is a native extension for air.

If you could let me know how I can go about doing this, I would appreciate!

David

UPDATE CODE:

```
var contactEditor:ContactEditor= new ContactEditor();
```

This is what I am using to create the new object for the contacteditor.

so if I use like :

```
contactEditor.ContactsSimple();
```

Nothing happens, I don't get the quick select for the ContactsSimple()...You can see on the site in one of the comments at the top.

UPDATE:

Hey I actually got it to link up but when I try and test it using this:

```
import pl.mllr.extensions.contactEditor.ContactEditor;

var contactEditor:ContactEditor;

contactEditor.getContactsSimple();
```

I get this error:

```
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class pl.mllr.extensions.contactEditor::ContactEditor could not be found.

    at runtime::ContentPlayer/loadInitialContent()
    at runtime::ContentPlayer/playRawContent()
    at runtime::ContentPlayer/playContent()
    at runtime::AppRunner/run()
    at ADLAppEntry/run()
    at global/runtime::ADLEntry()
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Flash Professional?
You just need to ANE file to the build path in your project.

> In Flash Professional CS6:
>
> Create a new project of the type AIR for iOS or AIR for Android.
>   Choose File > Publish Settings.
>   Click the wrench icon next to Script for ActionScript Settings.
>   Select the Library Path tab.
>   Click the Browse For Native Extension (ANE) File button and select the com.milkmangames.nativeextensions.RateBox.ane file.
>
> In Flash Builder 4.6:
>
> Go to Project Properties (right-click your project in Package Explorer and select Properties).
>   Select ActionScript Build Path and click the Native Extensions tab.
>   Click Add ANE and navigate to the com.milkmangames.nativeextensions.RateBox.ane file.
>
> In FlashDevelop:
>
> Copy the RateBoxAPI.swc file to your project folder.
>   In the explorer panel, right-click the SWC and select Add To Library.
>   Right-click the SWC file in the explorer panel again, select Options, and then select External Library.

Take a look at http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/ratebox-ane-ios-android.html

### Edit:

You need to instantiate the editor, as well as import the event file. The getContactsSimple() returns an array as well.

```
import pl.mllr.extensions.contactEditor.ContactEditor;
import pl.mllr.extensions.contactEditor.ContactEditorEvent;

var contactsEditor:ContactEditor = new ContactEditor();

var array:Array = contactsEditor.getContactsSimple();
```

But perhaps there is a bug with the ANE, 
 Error #3500: The extension context does not have a method with the name getContactsSimple.

You might have to rebuild the ANE.
http://forums.adobe.com/message/4574775

Comment: I figured that out by - going to actionscript settings choosing my .swc file for the plugin and setting it to external source as stated in the adobe follow-up.  Now nothing happens when I try and create an object for it, I don't get the options that would pop up while typing the code.  I don't know whats wrong.  If you could look at the plugin that I am talking about, the link is in my ?